# How to create a stylised Google maps app on android studio and a custom tiledlayer to show additional information that will be updated in realtime?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I wish to create a maps app which allows people to geotag media to it such as music or photos. The map should also be stylised accordingly to this design here: https://snazzymaps.com/style/151/ultra-light-with-labels What are the steps I need to take to create such an app using the google maps sdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible or the Google Maps Android API does not support custom styles, The only one that you can change here is the [Map types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_types) (Normal, Hybrid, Satellite, Terrain). Only the Google Maps JavaScript API can support this [style maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

If you check this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5463), you will see here that it is already requested to have a custom style maps in Google Maps Android API. Just check it always if there is an update about here.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will. Do you happen to know if there are any Map services like mapbox which support both styles and custom tile overlays?

Comment: You can try to check this [one](https://mangomap.com/how-it-works), but I have not tested it so far.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out